# css bug in ie8 login link comes down in navigation bar

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, internet-explorer-8

the login link in the the navigation bar comes down in ie8 
how to fix the bug

http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/5/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/48y2Q/5/

providing my code below

```
<li id="eMli" style="padding-left: 146px;">
<a id="eMlia" href="#about" style="background-color: #cba25e;">Login</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't think it's an IE8 bug, it comes down in Firefox too.

Comment: @robertc: thanks for your reply...i don't see it in firefox...can u tell how to fix it